# Can variable variables be used to dynamically assign class properties, so as to allow class constructors with variable arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, class, variables, properties, constructor

I am building a class and initially wanted to overload the constructs but discovered this is not allowed in PHP. My solution was using variable arguments for the one constructor. However, I am having some issues using string literals in a key => value pair and assigning the class properties. This leads me to ask my main question - is it actually possible to use variable variables to assign class properties via the constructor?

See example below:

```
class funrun{

   protected $run_id; 
   protected $fun_id; 
   protected $funrun_title; 
   protected $date; 

   function __construct(){

     if (func_num_args() > 0){
       $args = func_get_args(0); 
       foreach($args as $key => $value){
          $this->$key = $value;
       }

     $this->date = date();

     function __get($name){
        return $this->name; 
     }

     function __set($name,$value){
         $this->name = $value; 
     } 

}
```

This seems to correctly assign the values. But then when I do the following:

```
$settings = array ('run_id' => 5, 'fun_id' => 3); 
$fun_example = new funrun($settings); 
echo $fun_example->run_id;
```

I get an error that the getter method isn't functioning:

```
Undefined property: funrun::$name
```

However, when I switch the class code to $this->key, the class property doesn't seem to be assigned at all. When I do $fun_example->$run_id, nothing is returned.

What am I missing here? Is there anyway to use an array with string literals to assign class properties? If not, what is a good way to tackle the variable argument issue with constructors?

Comment: Why do you declare all your properties as protected, then provide magic methods that allow you to access them as if they were public? Why not just declare them public in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->name` is looking for a property named `name`. Variable properties are written as:

```
$this->$name
```

See the paragraph beginning with **Class properties may also be accessed using variable property names.** in the PHP documentation on [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Your constructor is incorrectly written. It's iterating over the argument list, expecting it to be an associative array. But you're passing the settings as a single argument. So it should be:

```
function __construct($args) {
    foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
    $this->date = time();
}
```

Comment: Hmm Barmar, I tried doing that, and though the property is set, I am then unable to access the variable by doing $fun_example->run_id. Does  php 5.4 even support variable variables using with $this? [See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php]. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Works now. Think I was confused between accessing a class property vs a variable property and totally didn't realize that my get and set methods needed to use variable property notation.